# File size of virtual file

Tags: c, filesystems, fuse, stat

I'm using FUSE to create an overlay filesystem, where directories are augmented with virtual entities. I am setting the file size of these entities to 0, because I have no way of knowing -- ahead of reading them, which is particularly expensive in my case -- what they should be.

However, there seems to be an obvious optimisation taking place, insofar as zero-length files don't incur any `read` call (only `open` and `release`).

My question therefore is simply, what should I set the file size to? I know symlinks have a size of their filename length; would this work, given it's not a symlink? Otherwise, the best I can do is provide a lower bound for the size... If `read` only has a file descriptor, chunk size and offset, presumably it reads 'til EOF rather than whatever `stat` can tell it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file size must be correct. A lot of code depends on this information, you can't simply omit it.

That means you need to figure out an efficient way to cache/precalculate this information.

Have a look at the sources of [cmdfs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cmdfs/) which runs a command on all files in the filesystem. [Linux Magazine has an overview article](http://www.linux-magazine.com/Online/Features/Cmdfs).

Comment: At what level is this dependent code? At the system call level, it appears (although it's likely that I'm wrong!) as though this isn't important; at the application level, I know the only software that reads this type of file doesn't rely on the file size... I can provide an estimate, if that's better, based on the lower bound.

Comment: The OS uses this value to determine when to send EOF. So literally everyone who reads data from the file needs it.

Comment: Is it not possible to raise that signal yourself?

Comment: @Xophmeister Send EOF yourself based on what?  The size of the actual file?  Just because the application code that you see doesn't use the size of a file doesn't mean the library or system calls that the application makes can work without a proper file size.

Comment: @AndrewHenle The virtual files I'm wanting to read are translations of sibling files (i.e., it's a file conversion overlay filesystem). I will know when to send the EOF once the conversion algorithm has reached the EOF of the sibling file.

Comment: ...Hence my aversion to precalculating the size: the origin files are very large -- several GBs -- and the conversion algorithm isn't particularly cheap.

Comment: There are existing translation file systems based on FUSE. They can encrypt or compress the data. To solve the EOF problem, they either save the original file size somewhere or they have a cache - when you open a file for the first time, the size gets calculated. If you run `du` on the second one, it's awfully slow.

Comment: I would have to use the cache option, because the point is to save disk space at the expense of memory and time. So presumably, ones FUSE `getattr` implementation must do this, which is called when a file is `stat`ed (or, alternatively, precalculate everything at start up)?

Comment: Yes; when a file is created/modified, you have to do the transformation once (maybe keep the result for some time; chances are that someone will be asking for it, soon) and write the size in a cache file somewhere.

Comment: I've added some links which should help.

Answer (score 3):

For file size is not known in advance, mount with option `-odirect_io` and set `st_size = 0`. I hope this will be helpful.

in fuse man page:

> ```
>   direct_io
>          This option disables the use of page cache (file content cache) in the kernel for this filesystem. This has several affects:
>
>   1.     Each read(2) or write(2) system call will initiate one or more read or write operations, data will not be cached in the kernel.
>
>   2.     The  return  value of the read() and write() system calls will correspond to the return values of the read and write operations.
>          This is useful for example if the file size is not known in advance (before reading it).
> ```