# Write data to FUSE named pipe

Tags: c, posix, fifo, fuse

I've created a virtual filesystem that presents its outputs as read-only named pipes (i.e., `S_IFIFO`).

As far as `getattr` is concerned, my host is showing that the permission mode is set correctly. However, when I attempt to open the pipe (e.g., `cat my_fuse_mount/my_pipe`), it apparently does so but no data flows.

I was expecting the `open`-`read`-`release` sequence to do the necessary to open and push data into a named pipe, but apparently not. When I run in debugging mode, FUSE's log doesn't seem to indicate that it's trying to do anything.

What FUSE operation/s is/are used to push data into a named pipe?

Comment: Try attaching a debugger and see where the process is stopped. I don't know how named pipes work on a FUSE filesystem, but usually when opening a pipe on Linux, the open call blocks until another process opens the other end of the pipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FUSE can create special files such as named pipes, but its read and write operations are only operational for normal files. If you want to implement a pipe, you would need something like [CUSE](https://lwn.net/Articles/308445/).

Comment: ...back to the drawing board, then!

Comment: Well, you do have the choice to just make a normal user-space app open the pipe and write to it. You might even be able to do so from within your fuse filesystem exectuable, though that could get a bit complicated.

Comment: My use case is trying to get around the ["knowing the filesize in advance" restriction](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31940722) by forcing the output through a named pipe (so zero size and no seeking) and, once it's been read through, the file can become a regular one with the correct attributes... Still, thanks for this; it's useful to know :)